# How to reduce the amount of lines needed for this logic?

Tags: python

I have a simple Python game where two players deal some damage to each other in turns until one player has 0 or less than 0 HP. I don't like how much I've repeated myself but I'm unsure how to fix this. I thought about using a list of players but then I'm unsure how to index the next player when it's their turn, without running into the list index out of range error.

**If this kind of question is not allowed please let me know and I will remove it.**

Below is my game logic to determine when a player has won. I may not have pasted in the exact code I have but it runs how it's expected locally.

```
def check_win_state(current_player):
  if current_player.get_player_health() > 0:
    return True
  elif current_player.get_player_health() <= 0:
    return False


def main():
  player1 = player.Player("Me")
  player2 = player.Player("You")

  while True:
    if check_win_state(player1):
      take_turn(player1, player2)
    else:
      print(f"\n{player2.get_player_name()} ({player2.get_player_health()} HP) wins! {player1.get_player_name()} has {player1.get_player_health()} HP left.\n")
      break
        
    if check_win_state(player2):
      take_turn(player2, player1)
    else:
      print(f"\n{player1.get_player_name()} ({player1.get_player_health()} HP) wins! {player2.get_player_name()} has {player2.get_player_health()} HP left.\n")
      break
```

Comment: Put the players in some kind of collection so it is easy to tell who is the "current" player and who is the other; then, each iteration, you swap them.

Comment: Well, `check_win_state` can be a single line: `return current_player.get_player_health() > 0`. It can also be modified to accept both players so calling code won't need to call it twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach to reduce code duplication in situations like these is to use a secondary variable to hold the primary variable. Here, instead of having different code for player1 and player2, we instead have just one code, and use the variables `current_player` and `opposing_player` to hold player1 and player2, and *swap with every iteration*.

```
def main():
  player1 = player.Player("Me")
  player2 = player.Player("You")

  current_player = player1
  opposing_player = player2

  while True:
    if check_win_state(current_player):
      take_turn(current_player, opposing_player)
    else:
      print(f"\n{opposing_player.get_player_name()} ({opposing_player.get_player_health()} HP) wins! {current_player.get_player_name()} has {current_player.get_player_health()} HP left.\n")
      break
    current_player, opposing_player = opposing_player, current_player
```

If you have more than two players, then a more extensible approach might be to have a `list` of players, and have an index rotate through the list with each iteration to specify which player is the 'current' one.

---

also, you can simplify `check_win_state()`:

```
def check_win_state(current_player):
    return current_player.get_player_health() > 0
```

because the check `a > b` returns a boolean anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the first function short using this logic:-

```
def check_win_state(current_player):
  return current_player.get_player_health() > 0:
```

And now you can create another function to do the work of inside while loop

```
def work_in_while(pl, another_pl):
  
  if check_win_state(pl):
    take_turn(pl, another_pl)
  else:  
     print(f"\n{another_pl.get_player_name()} ({another_pl.get_player_health()} HP) wins! {pl.get_player_name()} has {pl.get_player_health()} HP left.\n")
     return "kill"
```

And use it like:-

```
while True:
  if work_in_while(player1, player2) == "kill":
     break
  if work_in_while(player2, player1) == "kill":
     break
```